# While Loop using function not changing variable

Tags: python

How do I update the counter when using function in while loop? It keep gives me 2

```py
def Main(Counter):
    Counter = Counter +1
    print (Counter)
    
A = 1
while True:
    Main (A)
```

[image: Image 1]

Comment: 1) Please format your code.  In Python, indentation is *essential* ... but all the indentation is lost in your post.  Use the "code" icon.  2) Please do NOT post images of code or output.  Copy/paste text (and use the "code" icon) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are passing the same value of `A` each time in `Main()` function, it prints the same value `2`. To increase the `counter` you need to increment it in `while loop` and not in function itself.

```py
def Main(Counter):
    #Counter = Counter +1
    print (Counter)
    
A = 1
while True:
    Main(A)
    A += 1
```

---

If you want to increment the value inside the function for some reason, you can use `return` keyword to return the incremented value and store it in the variable.

```py
def Main(Counter):
    Counter = Counter +1
    print (Counter)
    return Counter

A = 1
while True:
    A = Main(A)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to increases the increment in the function?

Comment: @lzh I have edited my answer, let me no if this helps you

Comment: Yes, this helps with what i'm doing. Thanks!